# How to use apache commons (or any other library not part of the jdk) from Scala

Tags: scala, apache-commons-net

Seems like this should be simple, but I'm not a java guy. I was going to try and use the apache commons ftp component (org.apache.commons.net.ftp), but I don't know how to make it accessible to my scala code.

At the moment, I've just tried dropping the package into a directory, starting the scala repl from that directory, and issued:  import org.apache.commons.*
I'm told that apache is not a member of package org, which I assume to mean it can't find the code.

This really seems like it ought to be easy, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the jar into the class path. From REPL, that is done like so:

```
scala -classpath some.jar
```

If you are building a project, you might want to consider using a build tool like sbt (http://www.scala-sbt.org/) which allows you to specify dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

With SBT, you would put into your `build.sbt`

`libraryDependencies += "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "3.2"`

Comment: Thanks Franklin.  Looking forward to getting further into this stuff.

Comment: How did you know it was commons-net?